# Select nodeValue but exclude child elements

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

Let's say I have this code:

```
<p dataname="description">
Hello this is a description. <a href="#">Click here for more.</a>
</p>
```

How do I select the nodeValue of `p` but exclude `a` and it's content?

My current code:

```
$result = $xpath->query("//p[@dataname='description'][not(self::a)]");
```

I select it by `$result->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply appending /text() to your query should do the trick

```
$result = $xpath->query("//p[@dataname='description'][not(self::a)]/text()");
```

Comment: Could u pls explain why is it like that?

Comment: Without /text() you select the whole node including it's children. Element nodes does not have text themselves, instead it's text is stored in a child node called text node. nodeValue is used to get the text value of a node. Calling nodeValue on a node with children get's all child text nodes and concatenate them. With /text() you only grab the first child node of type text, and therefore only get the text of this text node

Answer (score 2):

Unsure if PHP's XPath supports this, but this XPath does the trick for me in Scrapy (Python based scraping framework):

```
$xpath->query('//p[@dataname='description']/text()[following-sibling::a]')
```

If this doesn't work, try Kristoffers solution, or you could also use a regex solution. For example:

`$output = preg_replace("~<.*?>.*?<.*?>~msi", '', $result->item(0)->nodeValue);`

That'll remove any HTML tag with any content in it, excluding text which is not encapsulated by HTML tags.